# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in .RunLoop.Modes.default when setting Timer

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Here's my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {  
    var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 60, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            print("timer")
        })

        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .RunLoop.Modes.default)
    }
}
```

It's showing an error on that `RunLoop` line at the end (specifically on the `.RunLoop.Modes.default` part):

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Just remove the period at the start of your string or simply use only `.default` -> `RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .default)`

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this:

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 60, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        print("timer")
    })

    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .default)
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Not sure how I missed that. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.